# Flipping the keys and constructing the values from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following two arrays:

```
$a1 = [56,60];
$a2 = [60 => 'aa', 61 => 'bb', 62 => 'cc', 63 => 'dd'];
```

I'm trying to apply `array_map` to construct a new array that would look like this:

```
Array
(
    [56] =>        
    [60] => aa
)
```

Basically what I need is to go through the first array, if I find it in the second array, I'll grab its corresponding value, otherwise, set it to an empty string. Is `array_map` the best way to go about this?

Comment: If you have tried, then show us the code you wrote so far

Comment: What are the criteria for considering __the best__?

Comment: `array_map` is just a function that makes your code concise. When you speak about `best way`, you should probably aim for efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple loop seems easiest to me, using `array_key_exists()`

```
$a1 = [56,60];
$a2 = [60 => 'aa',61 => 'bb',62 => 'cc',63 => 'dd'];

$new = [];

foreach ( $a1 as $key )  {
    if ( array_key_exists($key, $a2) ) {
        $new[$key] = $a2[$key];
    }
}

print_r($new);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [60] => aa
)
```

Or if you really want a blank occurance, this would work

```
$a1 = [56,60];
$a2 = [60 => 'aa',61 => 'bb',62 => 'cc',63 => 'dd'];

$new = [];

foreach ( $a1 as $key )  {
    $new[$key] = array_key_exists($key, $a2) ? $a2[$key] : null;
}

print_r($new);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [56] => 
    [60] => aa
)
```

Or even

```
$a1 = [56,60];
$a2 = [60 => 'aa',61 => 'bb',62 => 'cc',63 => 'dd'];

$new = [];

foreach ( $a1 as $key )  {
    $new[$key] = $a2[$key] ?? null;
}

print_r($new);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [56] => 
    [60] => aa
)
```

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Premature Key press :) Now added the missing bit

Comment: Also `$new[$key] = $a2[$key] ?? null;`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, I ended up using a loop too.